# Concatenate two dataframes and replacing NA values in R and transform the result in a csv file

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, concatenation

Hello I have two daframes in R, and I would like to concatenate them. The structure of the dfs its like that:

```
x <- data.frame(
  S1 = c(10, NA, NA),
  S2 = c(21, 22, 23)
)

y <- data.frame(
  S1 = c(11, 12, 13, 14),
  S2 = c(24, 25, 26, 27)
)
```

And I would like to have something like:

```
final <- data.frame(
S1 = c(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, NA, NA),
S2 = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27)
)
```

I've tried to use natural_join but it's give me a erro:

```
>library("rquery")

> final <- natural_join(ipeadata_d, ipeadata_d.cont, by = "ID",jointype = "FULL")
Error in natural_join.relop(dnodea, dnodeb, jointype = jointype, by = by,  : 
  rquery::natural_join.relop all tables must have all join keys, the following keys are not in some tables: ID
```

I Also tried the rbind, but the dataframe keeps the NA.

I would like to concatenate the dataframe like in the "final" example and would like to transform final in a csv file. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `natural_join` from the `rquery` package? Please include any necessary `library()` calls in your code.

Comment: Your first input data as well as `final` gives error `Error in data.frame(ID = c(1, 2), S1 = c(10, NA, NA), S2 = c(21, 22, 23)) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 2, 3`

Comment: The error you are getting is because one/both of your datasets doesn't have the `ID` column. "*all tables must have all join keys, the following keys are not in some tables: ID*" Check `names(ipeadata_d)` and `names(ipeadata_d.cont)` first.

Comment: Is `x` and `y` correct in this way? At least `x` can't work as it has different lengths  which are not a multiple from the others?

Comment: Thanks for the corrections guys, I edited the question.

Comment: What is the logic to change the `ID` values ? All the `ID` values of `y` file has changed to 4-7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may combine the two datasets using `bind_rows` and `sort` the columns putting `NA`'s at the last.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(x, y) %>%
  mutate(ID = row_number(), 
         across(c(S1, S2), sort, na.last = TRUE))

#  ID S1 S2
#1  1 10 21
#2  2 11 22
#3  3 12 23
#4  4 13 24
#5  5 14 25
#6  6 NA 26
#7  7 NA 27
```

Comment: Thanks @RonakShah for the answer, I really don't know much of R, but in my real case I have S1 to S12, how I would do in that case ? And the Id column is the # column. Sorry for the mistake. Thanks Again.

Comment: You can change `across(c(S1, S2), sort, na.last = TRUE)` to `across(S1:S12, sort, na.last = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks, but I can't get the columns names, is there any way to do that without puting the columns name ? Something like pandas loc/iloc ?

Comment: `across` can also accept column numbers. `across(1:12, ...)` `across(2:13, ...)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

- First - your example isn't reproducible because those `data.frames` do not have the same number of elements in each vector. I assume your ID vector should be of equal length to S1 and S2
- Second: it sounds like you can accomplish what you want in base R, without any special functions. You are just attempting to concatenate or "union" the 2 data.frames. R uses the command `rbind` to do this.

I am making an assumption here on what your desired output is.

Here is a working example using `rbind`:

```
x <- data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3),
  S1 = c(10, NA, NA),
  S2 = c(21, 22, 23)
)

y <- data.frame(
  ID = c(4, 5, 6, 7),
  S1 = c(11, 12, 13, 14),
  S2 = c(24, 25, 26, 27)
)

final <- rbind(x,y)

> rbind(x,y)
  ID S1 S2
1  1 10 21
2  2 NA 22
3  3 NA 23
4  4 11 24
5  5 12 25
6  6 13 26
7  7 14 27
```

For your reference, "merging" usually refers to combining 2 data.frames based on a shared column or key.

Comment: Thanks @izyda, sorry for the mistakes I will correct when I get home. I want something like you posted, but with the NA in the last 2 rows. Do you know if that's possible?

Comment: I edited the question, I think now it's represent in the right way what my question should be.